# Opengl ES 1.1 -- How do i generate an alpha mask at runtime and apply it to a texture

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I want to generate an alpha mask that will be a black square with a white arc of a random angle in the center an then apply it to a texture that is going to be rendered in the next frame. How do i do this in OpenGl

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to do is to mask over time a portion of my texture. I have a texture of a circular progress bar and I'm trying to reflect the progress by applying the mask which is supposed to be generated in runtime by drawing a white arc on a black square. And the question here is how do i generate this mask and apply it to my texture further at the rendering stage in a not expensive way.(I've tried the way with canvas(from new bitmap) and further manipulations with canvas but I really don't like this approach. )

Comment: What particular part of this is giving you a hard time? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I want to find a good and fast way of doing that but i'm stuck on new Canvas(sourceBitmap) and further manipulations with canvas and there is one more thing to say doing that way i need to send bitmap each time to gpu and recycle the old bitmap and so on...

Comment: I think you have to explain the problem a bit more. Is the alpha mask fixed or does it change over time? How does the arc look like...perhaps  the mask can be computed in a shader.